# WCF Service Content Type Issue

Tags: c#, wcf, mime-types

I have a wcf web servis. It works properly on our iis application server. Now I need to move this application into another server. Without changing anything, it doesn't work new server. The problem is service response type turned text\html. When I have tried on soap ui at header tab:

> Content-Type  text/html; charset=UTF-8

When I tried in a simple console application I have got following error:

> The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does
>   not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8)

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I just realized that It work with this binding settings:

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Binding1" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="52428800" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

When I change security mode to "None" (that I need) content type is become text\html

Comment: Some code, configuration files etc would be good to diagnose. Otherwise I'll need my crystall ball.

Comment: How are you calling the service ? Show some code.